# How to call an api to show the response inside an angular modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ui.bootstrap

I have a list of nodes showing on my home and when you click on the title of one node, a modal should be opened to display that node's detail, I'm working this way:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('EventsApp.controllers', ['infinite-scroll','ui.bootstrap','ngRoute']);
eventsApp.controller('eventsController', ['$scope','$modal','eventsAPIservice', function($scope, $modal, eventsAPIservice){
    $scope.openModal = function(id, size, animationsEnabled){
            var modalInstance;
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'templates/eventModal.html',
                controller: 'eventModalInstanceController',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    event: function(){
                        /* Here I make the call to the api */
                        eventsAPIservice.getEventById(id).success(function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                            return response;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
    };
}]);
```

And the modal instance is this:

```
eventsApp.controller('eventModalInstanceController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'event', function($scope, $modalInstance, event){

    $scope.eventDetail = event;
    console.log(event);
    $scope.save = function(param){
        console.log(param);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

The problem is that when I **console.log(response)** on the resolve, it show correctly the data, but it it's not passed correctly to **eventModalInstanceController** as the parameter 'event', so when I **console.log(event)** it shows undefined on console.

My modal template is this:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">{{ eventDetail.title }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>{{ eventDetail.eid }}</p>
  <p>{{ eventDetail.description }}</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

My question is where do I have to make the API call and how should I pass it to the instance controller

Comment: so you mean eventModalInstanceController should be on another angular.module() ? sorry, I'm new to angular

Comment: create a demo of what you have

Answer (score 0):

**The Reason Why:**

It should be the visibility of the variable `resolve` so if you need to access to `modalInstance` you have to generate a function that has access to that variable.

*So in your case:*

```
$scope.openModal = function(id, size, animationsEnabled){
    var modalInstance;
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'templates/eventModal.html',
        controller: 'eventModalInstanceController',
        size: size,
        resolve: {
            event: function(){
                /* Here I make the call to the api */
                eventsAPIservice.getEventById(id).success(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    updateEvent(response);
                    return response;
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function updateEvent(response) {
        modalInstance.eventDetail = response
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just moved all **eventModalInstanceController** into the 'controller' attribute in **$modal.open**, like this:

```
$scope.openModal = function(selectedEvent, size, animationsEnabled){
            var modalInstance;
            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'templates/eventModal.html',
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance, event){

                    $scope.event = event;
                    $scope.save = function(param){
                        console.log(param);
                    };

                    $scope.cancel = function(){
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                },
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    event: function(){
                        return selectedEvent;

                    }
                }                      
            });
};
```

I don't know if it's a good practice but it worked.